# Не устанавливает приложение android

Tags: android

После успешного билда ничего не происходит, хотя должна начаться установка приложения.

Не работает как на физическом устройстве, так и на эмуляторе.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Build Log**

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
34 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 30 up-to-date
```

Comment: а в сообщениях в процессе билда ничего не пишет?

Comment: @Andrew вообще ничего

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалось в том, что какой-то "умник" (не я), обновил Android Studio с версиии 4.1 Canary 2 на 4.1 Canary 3, а там походу какие - то проблемы